# Sitecore Serilization Roles Doesn't Get Created on XM Cloud Environments

Tags: xm-cloud, serialization

I have setup Sitecore Serialization configuraiton for roles and was successfully able to merge pull those from local instance into project files.

```json
{
  "$schema": "../.sitecore/schemas/ModuleFile.schema.json",
  "namespace": "ContentSettings",
  "items": {
    ...
  },
  "roles": [
    {
      "domain": "SXA",
      "pattern": "Admin"
    },
    {
      "domain": "SXA",
      "pattern": "Author"
    },
    {
      "domain": "SXA",
      "pattern": "Designer"
    },
    {
      "domain": "Client",
      "pattern": "Site Collection *"
    },
 ...
```

And those roles are serialized under `/src/items/_roles` folder.

But when we run the XM Cloud deployment, it doesn't copy those roles into our XM Cloud environment.

Is there anything extra needed to be done other than explained config configuration in xm cloud documentation ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the default way that XM Cloud deploys the serialization. The SCS files are used to generate an Item as Resources(IAR) file and that is layered into the XM Cloud instance.

Roles cannot be added via an IAR file.

To add the roles, you would need to use the `scsModules` post deploy action in the `xmcloud.build.json` file.

You need to create an SCS module that is used to serialize the roles, then in the `xmcloud.build.json` add a section to the post deploy actions:

```json
"postActions": {
  "actions": {
    "scsModules": {
      "modules": ["Module1","Module2"]
    }
  }
}
```

This uses the SCS sync action post deployment to deploy what is in the modules.

For the "modules" array, you have to provide "namespace" value mentioned on your .module.json configuration

Ref:

- https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/the-xm-cloud-build-configuration.html